# Exclude group in Regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match the power value of a certain number using Regex:
Exemple: A^2 --> num_pow = 2

```
power = "(\^[+-]?[1-9]\d*)"
num_pow1 = "(?P<num_pow1>" + power + ")"
num_pow2 = "(?P<num_pow2>" + power + ")"
```

currently this code will return "^2" rather than "2".
I tried using "?:" without any sucess.

Comment: Read about using _capture groups_ in regular expressions.

Comment: You regex [is invalid](https://regex101.com/r/uGNykt/2).

Comment: You could try something like `r"\^(?P<num_pow>[+-]?[1-9]\d*)"`.

Comment: indeed, there is a mistake in the power regex, it should be : power = "(\^[+-]?[1-9]\d*)"
The think is I would like to reuse the pattern "power" but each time with a different group (and by excluding the ^ of course)

Answer (score -1):

```
power = "\^([+-]?[1-9]\d*)"
num_pow1 = "(?P<num_pow1>" + power.group(1) + ")"
num_pow2 = "(?P<num_pow2>" + power.group(1) + ")"
```

Comment: `power` is a _string_, so `power.group(1)` is not defined (code snippet throws an exception)?

Comment: same here, power.group(1) doesn't return anything. 
Any other idees?

Comment: yeah, I get that, was more focused figuring out "stack overflow", I botched understanding the question